# Rotated Table ignore lower margin (and remove page number)

Tags: tables

I have a big latex table which I rotated to fit the page. However, the table is to big for the page. Is there anyway I can make the table ignore the lower margin and remove the page number on this page?

Below a picture of the table in question. The pink boxes have text in it.[image]

Here my preamble and table:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage[autolinebreaks]{mcode0}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,margin=\parindent,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

%\usepackage{showframe}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={210mm,297mm},
 left=20mm,
 right=20mm,
 top=23mm,
 bottom=30mm,
 }

\parskip = 0pt
\pagestyle{plain}
\setlength{\parskip}{.0in}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}


\begin{document}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
\baselineskip21pt


\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}
\FloatBarrier
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{sidewaystable}[!htbp]
\footnotesize
  \centering
  \caption{Title}
  \caption*{Long Long description here}
\begin{tabular}{lccccccccccccccccccccccc}
\hline
\multicolumn{24}{c}{Panel A}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    \\ \hline
                      & 1                  & label               &                      & 5                   & label               &                      & 2                   & label               &                      & 6                   & label               &                      & 3                   & label               &                      & 7                  & label               &                      & 4                   & label               &                      & 8                 & label               \\ \cline{2-3} \cline{5-6} \cline{8-9} \cline{11-12} \cline{14-15} \cline{17-18} \cline{20-21} \cline{23-24}
Long Long Name Here          & 0.06                 & 0.35                 &                      & -0.07                & -0.49                &                      & 0.17                 & 1.01                 &                      & 0.21                 & 1.32                 &                      & -0.06                & -0.48                &                      & 0.20                 & 1.60                 &                      & 0.42                 & 3.21*                &                      & 0.20                 & 3.19*                \\
Long Long Name Here               & -0.01                & -0.05                &                      & 0.03                 & 0.14                 &                      & -0.36                & -1.66*               &                      & 0.07                 & 0.35                 &                      & -0.09                & -0.39                &                      & -0.32                & -1.53                &                      & 0.25                 & 1.29                 &                      & -0.14                & -1.26                \\
Long Long Name Here          & -0.16                & -1.15                &                      & -0.12                & -0.89                &                      & 0.09                 & 0.64                 &                      & -0.27                & -1.81*               &                      & 0.18                 & 1.42                 &                      & -0.06                & -0.49                &                      & 0.21                 & 1.48                 &                      & 0.11                 & 2.03*                \\
Long Long Name Here      & -0.06                & -0.36                &                      & 0.16                 & 0.88                 &                      & 0.19                 & 1.07                 &                      & -0.07                & -0.33                &                      & 0.03                 & 0.17                 &                      & 0.14                 & 0.83                 &                      & 0.61                 & 3.67*                &                      & 0.03                 & 0.33                 \\
Long Long Name Here  & -0.33                & -2.65*               &                      & 0.03                 & 0.21                 &                      & 0.05                 & 0.44                 &                      & -0.07                & -0.47                &                      & 0.16                 & 1.34                 &                      & 0.10                 & 0.89                 &                      & 0.33                 & 2.69*                &                      & 0.09                 & 1.57                 \\
Long Long Name Here     & 0.47                 & 3.21*                &                      & 0.38                 & 2.28*                &                      & 0.03                 & 0.24                 &                      & -0.18                & -1.33                &                      & -0.34                & -2.38*               &                      & 0.15                 & 1.44                 &                      & -0.13                & -1.01                &                      & -0.03                & -0.51                \\
Long Long Name Here     & -0.11                & -1.04                &                      & -0.23                & -1.70*               &                      & -0.05                & -0.49                &                      & -0.06                & -0.49                &                      & -0.05                & -0.36                &                      & 0.22                 & 1.97*                &                      & 0.23                 & 2.59*                &                      & 0.07                 & 1.23                 \\
Long Long Name Here             & -0.03                & -0.16                &                      & -0.11                & -0.48                &                      & 0.04                 & 0.21                 &                      & 0.28                 & 1.24                 &                      & 0.73                 & 3.49*                &                      & 0.07                 & 0.39                 &                      & 0.70                 & 3.97*                &                      & 0.13                 & 1.40                 \\
Long Long Name Here   & 0.17                 & 1.69*                &                      & -0.01                & -0.07                &                      & 0.07                 & 0.61                 &                      & 0.48                 & 4.45*                &                      & -0.18                & -1.80*               &                      & 0.27                 & 2.16*                &                      & 0.22                 & 2.51*                &                      & 0.16                 & 3.30*                \\
Long Long Name Here                 & 0.13                 & 1.18                 &                      & 0.05                 & 0.44                 &                      & 0.05                 & 0.41                 &                      & 0.24                 & 1.93*                &                      & -0.25                & -2.25*               &                      & -0.04                & -0.40                &                      & 0.04                 & 0.42                 &                      & 0.02                 & 0.29                 \\
Long Long Name Here                & -0.24                & -1.56                &                      & -0.27                & -1.42                &                      & -0.10                & -0.58                &                      & -0.05                & -0.35                &                      & 0.36                 & 2.48*                &                      & -0.40                & -2.35*               &                      & -0.56                & -4.17                &                      & -0.19                & -2.67*               \\
Long Long Name Here                  & -0.37                & -2.53*               &                      & -0.25                & -1.22                &                      & -0.28                & -2.00*               &                      & -0.02                & -0.13                &                      & 0.06                 & 0.40                 &                      & -0.29                & -2.41*               &                      & -0.13                & -1.10                &                      & -0.01                & -0.15                \\ \hline
                      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{24}{c}{Panel B}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        \\ \hline
                      & 1                  & label               &                      & 5                   & label               &                      & 2                   & label               &                      & 6                   & label               &                      & 3                   & label               &                      & 7                  & label               &                      & 4                   & label               &                      & 8                 & label               \\ \cline{2-3} \cline{5-6} \cline{8-9} \cline{11-12} \cline{14-15} \cline{17-18} \cline{20-21} \cline{23-24}
1                 & 0.12                 & 1.46                 &                      & 0.25                 & 2.84*                &                      & -0.13                & -1.66*               &                      & -0.01                & -0.15                &                      & -0.24                & -2.99*               &                      & 0.10                 & 1.41                 &                      & -0.05                & -0.59                &                      & -0.01                & -0.34                \\
2                     & 0.05                 & 0.60                 &                      & 0.01                 & 0.11                 &                      & 0.14                 & 2.11*                &                      & -0.06                & -0.79                &                      & -0.16                & -2.37*               &                      & 0.05                 & 0.82                 &                      & 0.13                 & 2.14*                 &                      & 0.04                 & 1.19                 \\
3                     & -0.11                & -1.13                &                      & -0.15                & -1.72*               &                      & 0.00                 & -0.02                &                      & 0.03                 & 0.31                 &                      & 0.10                 & 1.39                 &                      & 0.08                 & 1.16                 &                      & 0.13                 & 1.77*                &                      & 0.04                 & 1.01                 \\
4                     & -0.28                & -2.55*               &                      & -0.21                & -1.56                &                      & 0.02                 & 0.21                 &                      & 0.05                 & 0.58                 &                      & 0.27                 & 2.30*                &                      & 0.10                 & 0.85                 &                      & 0.16                 & 1.78*                &                      & 0.01                 & 0.27                 \\
5                   & 0.19                 & 1.00                 &                      & -0.04                & -0.25                &                      & 0.22                 & 1.28                 &                      & 0.07                 & 0.39                 &                      & 0.25                 & 1.71*                &                      & -0.11                & -0.76                &                      & 0.28                 & 1.71*                &                      & -0.02                & -0.32                \\ \hline
                      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{24}{c}{Panel C}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
                      & 1                  & label               &                      & 5                   & label               &                      & 2                   & label               &                      & 6                   & label               &                      & 3                   & label               &                      & 7                  & label               &                      & 4                   & label               &                      & 8                 & label               \\ \cline{2-3} \cline{5-6} \cline{8-9} \cline{11-12} \cline{14-15} \cline{17-18} \cline{20-21} \cline{23-24}
1                & -0.01                & -0.05                &                      & -0.12                & -0.56                &                      & 0.06                 & 0.25                 &                      & 0.50                 & 1.90*                &                      & 0.67                 & 2.65*                &                      & -0.04                & -0.19                &                      & 1.00                 & 4.34*                &                      & 0.33                 & 3.34*                \\
2                     & -0.13                & -0.80                &                      & -0.18                & -1.16                &                      & -0.01                & -0.08                &                      & 0.33                 & 1.86                 &                      & 0.56                 & 3.66*                &                      & 0.04                 & 0.31                 &                      & 0.57                 & 3.71*                &                      & 0.24                 & 3.60*                \\
3                     & -0.12                & -0.93                &                      & -0.07                & -0.64                &                      & 0.03                 & 0.22                 &                      & 0.14                 & 0.99                 &                      & 0.25                 & 2.04*                &                      & 0.07                 & 0.70                 &                      & 0.58                 & 4.43*                &                      & 0.24                 & 4.66*                \\
4                     & -0.02                & -0.23                &                      & -0.13                & -1.37                &                      & 0.13                 & 1.33                 &                      & 0.07                 & 0.70                 &                      & 0.08                 & 0.84                 &                      & -0.03                & -0.41                &                      & 0.19                 & 2.30*                &                      & 0.11                 & 2.75*                \\
5                 & 0.00                 & -0.04                &                      & 0.13                 & 1.82*                &                      & 0.01                 & 0.08                 &                      & -0.03                & -0.25                &                      & -0.04                & -0.63                &                      & 0.08                 & 1.13                 &                      & -0.15                & -2.41*               &                      & -0.08                & -2.62*               \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

  \label{tab:reference}%
\end{sidewaystable}%



\clearpage


\end{document}
```

Comment: A code to test would be helpful. Let me just say that, *a priori*, I would play with `the value of `\tabcolsep` (the intercolumn space).

Comment: Are you using a float?  If not, use \thispagestyle{empty} and \newgeometry (geometry package).  If yes, use the afterpage package to force the float to go on a particular page.  Also, consider using \resizebox from the graphicx package.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers. I have included my preamble and table code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out a way of solving it by doing:

```
\newgeometry{left=3cm,bottom=0.1cm}
\thispagestyle{empty} 

table code
\restoregeometry
```